# Ошибка 500 в Azure несмотря на то, что в VS все работает отлично

Tags: asp.net-core, развертывание, azure, http-status-code-500

Сегодня работал над проектом, задеплоил его и бд, все работало нормально. Потом добавил Identity, новую бд, подтверждение по почте через SendGrid, снова задеплоил, теперь ничего не грузит, просто ошибка 500. При этом в студии все отлично работает. 
В чем может быть причина? Если нужно, скину проект на гитхабе, но подумал, что никто смотреть и искать не станет, но вдруг есть известные какие-то проблемы с тем, что я перечислил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включил Application Insight в Azure, выяснил, что виной стало исключение, связанное с использованием user-secrets, которые рекомендуется использовать в гайдах от Microsoft по Identity, SendGrid, Google OAuth2. Нужно занести ключи в appsettings.json вместо хранилища секретов, тогда все заработает